# Querying Data using Linq for 1-n navigation path

Tags: c#, linq

I have following relation in my table.

`TravelPlan (Table A)`

`Destination(table D)` and `Users(table E)` are used to build the Travel choices ie, a entry in `Travelplan` can includes multiple `Destination` and  `User` (mapping are stored in another mapping table  ,ie 1 to n)

`DestinationTravelPlanMapping(TableC)`
`UserTravelPlanMapping(TableD)`.

but I am not able to complete the query.what wrong in this

I need to fetch the all `Unique` `destinations` for a given user using Linq.

```
 var userId=6;
return context.TravelPlan
                        .Include(x => x.DestinationTravelPlanMapping)
                        .Include(x => x.DestinationTravelPlanMapping.Select(y => y.Destination))
                        .Include(x => x.UserTravelPlanMapping.Select(y => y.UserId == userId))
// the below select statement is throwing error
                        .Select(x => x.DestinationTravelPlanMapping.Select(y => new Destination
                        {
                            Id = y.Destination.Id,
                            Name = y.Destination.Name
                        }));
```

Comment: `the below select statement is throwing error` What error?

Comment: What does the function signature look like?

Comment: 1) You probably don't need `.Include` here. 2) I would suggest that either you include a diagram of the relationships, or find some other way to represent the entity relationships with text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return context.TravelPlans
    .Where(x => x.UserTravelPlanMapping.Any(y => y.UserID == userID))
    .SelectMany(x => x.DestinationTravelPlanMapping.Select(y => y.Destination))
    .Distinct();
```

You want the unique `Destination`s from the `TravelPlans` which have a `UserTravelPlanMapping` with a `UserID` matching the variable `userID`.